# A hausdorff topology that is not regular

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Consider, for $a$ and $b$ positive integers, the set $U(a,b)=\{an+b\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}\cap \mathbb{N}$. The set $\{U(a,b)\mid (a;b)=1\}$ is a basis for some topology on the naturals (I proved this).

Show that this space is Hausdorff but not regular.

Take $n, m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m\neq n$. I don't know hot to find disjoint open sets for each. Any hints?

To prove it's not regular, I tried taking the point $1$ and the set $C=\{2n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Any open set $W$ such that $1\in W$ will have a basic set contained in it, but I don't see the problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't $U(mn+1,m), U(mn+1,n)$ work?

Comment: Well, $m\in U(mn+1,m)$ since $m=(mn+1)(0)+m$. The same for $n$. If $w\in U(mn+1,m)\cap U(mn+1,n)$, then $(mn+1)(k_1)+m=w=(mn+1)(k_2)+n$.

Comment: Then $(mn+1)(k_1)+m-(mn+1)(k_2)-n=0$?

Comment: $mn k_1+k_1+m-mnk_2-k_2-n=0$

Comment: Mod the last by mn+1, you get $m \equiv n$. Methinks that's a contradiction, so no overlap.

Comment: Not regular ended up being much more difficult - I'm not sure what a useful hint would be besides the full answer, which I've edited in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Hausdorff:

Consider $U(mn+1, m), U(mn+1,n)$. Since $\gcd(a\cdot k + 1, a) =1$, these are both basis elements, hence open. Further, they're disjoint, as if there exists $j,k$ such that
$$ (mn+1)k+m = (mn+1)j+n$$
Then $m = n $ modulo $mn+1$, but $m, n$ are distinct, both positive and less than $mn+1$, so this cannot happen. Thus there are no such $j,k$, and the sets are disjoint.

Now, for regular. Take $C,p$ as you've outlined above. Suppose for contradiction there are disjoint open sets $A, B$ containing $p, C$ respectively. Note that $A$ must contain a set of the form $U(k_1,1)$, where $k_1$ is even (otherwise $k_1+1 \in C$ and $k_1+1 \in U(k_1,1)$), as the only other basis sets containing $1$ also contain all of $\mathbb{N}$ - which obviously intersects with $B$.

Likewise, $B$ must contain contain $U(k_2,k_1)$ (with $gcd(k_2,k_1) = 1$) as it must contain $k_1$ (a positive even number, which is in $C$). Again if we have some other open set $U(a,b)$ containing $k_1$, then $a*n + b = k_1$ for some $n$, and hence this open set contains $U(a, a*n+b) = U(k_2, k_1)$.

However, $U(k_1,1) \cap U(k_2,k_1) \neq \emptyset$, because of [Bezouts identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), since $gcd(k_2,k_1) = 1$, we have $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$i k_2 + j k_1 = 1 \implies i k_2 + k_1 = 1 - (j-1) k_1$$

To turn this element into a natural number (so we get our intersection) add a sufficiently large multiple of $k_1 \cdot k_2$ to each side. This is clearly an element of both $U(k_2, k_1)$ and $U(k_1, 1)$, so $A,B$ are disjoint. A contradiction.

Comment: I don't see why the fact that $m=n (\text{mod }mn+1)$ is a contradiction to the disjointness of $U(mn+1,m)$ and $U(mn+1,n)$

Comment: Ah, so this is a modulo thing. Mod $a$ means remainder when you divide by $a$. Note because $m,n$ are positive, $mn+1$ is bigger than both, hence the remainder would just be themselves. For example, the remainder of $3$ divided by $7$ is $3$. But remember we have that $m \neq n$, so if the sets do intersect we must have $m \equiv n$ mod $mn+1$ $\implies m =n$ and $m \neq n$ (by assumption). That's the contradiction.

Comment: I see now, thank you. Another question: how do you know that $1\in U(k_1,1)$? It could happen that $1=(1)(-1)+2$, right? Then $1\in U(1,2)$.

Comment: Ah, yes. The other case is always equivalent to $U(1,0) =$ everything. Note $U(1,\cdot)$ is the same such set. So if one is included in one of these sets, there is no chance of being disjoint.

Comment: Great! And those are the only three cases for $1=a\cdot n+b$ are ($a\in \mathbb{N}$, $n=0$ and $b=1$) or ($a=1$, $n=1$ and $b=0$) or ($a=1$, $n=-1$ and $b=2$)?

Comment: Merge the last two cases to $a=1, b \in \mathbb N$, then yes. For any $b$, you can use $n=1-b$

Comment: Okay, so the only cases are ($a\in \mathbb{N}$, $n=0$ & $b=1$) or ($a=1$, $b\in \mathbb{N}$ & $1-b$). So either $1\in U(\cdot,1)$ or $1\in U(1, \cdot)$. But, as you said before, $U(1,\cdot)=\mathbb{N}=U(1,0)$. So in this case the neighborhood of $1$ would intersect any other nonempty set, so this is not the case. Then we must have $1\in U(\cdot,1)$.

Comment: Say $1\in U(k_1, 1)$. Then $k_1$ is even because if not, taking $n=1$, $k_1\cdot n+1=k_1+1=2p\in C\cap U(k_1,1)$. We wouldn't want that. So $k_1$ is even.

Comment: And for the other part, we want a set $U(a,b)$ (with $a$ and $b$ relatively prime) such that $U(a,b)\subset \{2n\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. So $a$ and $b$ can't both be even. But we can't know anything else from $a$ and $b$, can we? Then, because $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then $1=aj+bi\implies 1=bi+aj+a-a\implies bi+a=1+a-aj=1+a(1-j)$. So $aj+bi\in U(a,1)$

Comment: I get lost at this point.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some of your previous questions. At this point, I might suggest opening another question for future clarifications (link this for reference perhaps?) - The question assumes a bit of number theory that I'm not sure how to work without, but it would be inappropriate to outline it all here. 

Importantly, $U(a,b) \subset B, C \subset B$ - not $U(a,b) \subset C$ - with $B$ a neighborhood of $C$. Finally, note we can require very specific $a,b$, namely the $k_1$ from earlier, and some new integer $k_2$. This lets us use Bezouts to finish.